# Android Wear, Watchface type detection - Round Or Square

Tags: android, wear-os

I have one activity, ExampleActivity

```
    <activity android:name="com.android.ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowEmbedded="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

With this define in manifiest, round layout is detect without problems.

But with this manifiest, the SAME activity, the SAME code not works.

```
    <activity android:name="com.android.ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowEmbedded="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview" android:resource="@drawable/example_watch_background" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

For detect round layout, moto 360 device, using onApplyWindowInsets or onReadyForContent, but the same problem.

Any idea because when i used this category, com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND, not works ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the entire manifest?

Answer (score 1):

With the new SDK, you need to do it like it's shown on [Android Wear for Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html)

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    boolean mIsRound;
    int mChinSize;

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        mIsRound = insets.isRound();
        mChinSize = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
    }
    ...
}
```

Here, as you can see, you may also get a value of a bottom screen gap (ex. Moto 360).

Answer (score -1):

Until the new andrioid smartwatch SDK is realeased, you can't use setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener / onApplyWindowInsets on custom watch face. This functionality only works on smartwatch app's (without add  in manifest).

To know if the clock face is round, you can use:

```
public static boolean heightSameAsWidth(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);

    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    return height == width;
}

private void checkIfWatchIsRound() {
    if (heightSameAsWidth(getApplicationContext())) {
        isRound = false;
    } else {
        isRound = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work on Huawei watch because height = width on huawei